# Mobile scroll too long leaving white space below text

Tags: html, css, scroll, vertical-scrolling

http://www.cllrart.com/more

In mobile browsers, the page scrolls way below the last text on the page causing some white space to appear at the end. How could I possibly remove this?

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like your css `.entry` class has a large bottom-margin.

```
.entry {
    margin: 4.5em 0; // <-- Reducing this will help
 }
```

You can try this:

```
.entry {
    margin: 4.5em 0 0; // <-- Doing this might be what you're looking for.
 }
```

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

What is your css / html for your mobile media query? I would check your height or padding on a specific div or element.

Answer (score 0):

```
p {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
}
```

I think this is the issue for you. The margin is adding extra space, you should be able to remove all the `overflow: hidden;` you've added to the `overflow-container` and `body` tags if you adjust this on mobile devices. I'd write a media query to target the devices you are having issues on.

It would be helpful to be more specific, for future reference, such as what browser this issue is showing up on or which device is having the issue. Screenshots might also be helpful to better illustrate what the issue is. Just some tips for next time!

Well, I hope this helps you out!